# using exports inside db.open() callback - mongoose/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `user.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName');

var User = mongoose.model('user', { username: String, password: String });

exports.User = User;
```

I am accessing the exposed `User` variable in other files.

However, I changed the file to this according to docs:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('connection open');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var User = mongoose.model('user', { username: String, password: String });
    exports.User = User;
});
```

However, the `User` variable is undefine now in the other file.

Why is it so and how do I expose the `User` variable to other files?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which documentation you looked at, but I don't think that this is a good way to organise `Mongoose` schema. It would probably be better to define the schema in a separate file and then export that file. Here an example :

**app.js** :

```
var express = require('express');     
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb:mongoURI');    

var db = mongoose.connection;
var userModel = require('../models/user.js');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    // Use userModel  ...
});

var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
app.get('/users/list', userRoute.list);

app.listen(3000);
```

**models/user.js** :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   ,Schema = mongoose.Schema
   ,ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    id : ObjectId,
    name : {type : String, default : ''},
    email : {type : String, default : ''}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**routes/users.js** :

```
var user = require('../models/user.js');

exports.list = function(req, res) {
    user.find(function(err, users) {
        res.send(users);
    });
};
```

Comment: I was looking at this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html. It says "let's assume that all following code is within this callback" and then defines the schema.

Comment: It is through an example to illustrate a concept, I do not think it advisable to do so in a real application.